# Uploading files through Ajax are duplicate

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to uploads file through Ajax and FormData objects. Why my files are duplicate ?

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#send');
document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', sendForm, false);
function sendForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formElement;
  var formData;
  var xhr;
  var JSONObject;
  formElement = document.querySelector('#form');
  formData = new FormData(formElement);
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');
  var files = fileInput.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    formData.append('file[]', file, file.name);
  }
  console.log(...formData);
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  /**/
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <label for="firstname">Prénom
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="30" />
 </label>
 <label for="lastname">Nom
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="30" />
 </label>
 <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
 <button id="send" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What's wrong with my code? Is my loop incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do two things, 1. `new FormData();` + loop 2. `new FormData(formElement);` no loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are manually appending your files to the `formData`, where they already are.

After commenting unnecessary code, your code works fine.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#send');
document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', sendForm, false);
function sendForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formElement;
  var formData;
  var xhr;
  var JSONObject;
  formElement = document.querySelector('#form');
  formData = new FormData(formElement);
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');
  /*
  The code that appends files in the formData, where thhey already here : 
  var files = fileInput.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    formData.append('file[]', file, file.name);
  }*/
  console.log(...formData);
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  /**/
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <label for="firstname">Prénom
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="30" />
 </label>
 <label for="lastname">Nom
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="30" />
 </label>
 <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
 <button id="send" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oops. I'm confused. Thanks RogerC.

Comment: @Vincent De rien. Ça arrive :)